# Query causing values to not be included

Tags: sql, oracle

In the following I am looking up a value in a legacy database my company has.

```
SELECT DISTINCT DLR.CIRCUIT_DESIGN_ID AS "CID",
                DLR.ECCKT AS "CIRCUIT",
                CI.LOCATION_ID_2 AS "SITE ID",
                CI.EXCHANGE_CARRIER_CIRCUIT_ID AS "ID",
                CI.RATE_CODE as "Rate",
                DLR.ACCESS_CUSTOMER_NAME AS "CUSTOMER SITE NAME",
                ADR.HOUSE_NBR || ' ' || ADR.STREET_NM || ' ' || ADR.STREET_SUF || ' ' || ADR.CITY_NAME || ' ' || ADR.STATE_CODE || ' ' || ADR.ZIP_CODE AS "CUSTOMER ADDRESS"
       FROM DESIGN_LAYOUT_REPORT DLR, CIRCUIT CI, MSAG_ADDR_LOC ADR
       WHERE CI.CIRCUIT_DESIGN_ID = DLR.CIRCUIT_DESIGN_ID 
             AND CI.LOCATION_ID_2 = ADR.LOCATION_ID
             AND CI.CIRCUIT_DESIGN_ID IN (
                 SELECT DISTINCT CIRCUIT_DESIGN_ID
                        FROM DLR_CIRCUIT_DESIGN_LINE
                        WHERE LOCATION LIKE '%  <some value from other code>   %'
                 )
```

My problem comes from the fact that ADR only has info for some of the values I search which is causing this query to not include all the values I need. DLR and CI always have values. How would I make this query return everything and just give me blank returns for the values that do not match an ADR entry?

Comment: "info for some"? empty strings or sql nulls for the missing data? If it's null, then you'll have to use coalesce()-type operations to switch those nulls into something that's not-null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would just need an outer join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DLR.CIRCUIT_DESIGN_ID AS "CID",
DLR.ECCKT AS "CIRCUIT",
CI.LOCATION_ID_2 AS "SITE ID",
CI.EXCHANGE_CARRIER_CIRCUIT_ID AS "ID",
CI.RATE_CODE as "Rate",
DLR.ACCESS_CUSTOMER_NAME AS "CUSTOMER SITE NAME",
ADR.HOUSE_NBR || ' ' || ADR.STREET_NM || ' ' || ADR.STREET_SUF || ' ' || ADR.CITY_NAME || ' ' || ADR.STATE_CODE || ' ' || ADR.ZIP_CODE AS "CUSTOMER ADDRESS"
FROM DESIGN_LAYOUT_REPORT DLR, CIRCUIT CI, MSAG_ADDR_LOC ADR
WHERE CI.CIRCUIT_DESIGN_ID = DLR.CIRCUIT_DESIGN_ID 
  AND CI.LOCATION_ID_2 = ADR.LOCATION_ID (+)
  AND CI.CIRCUIT_DESIGN_ID IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT CIRCUIT_DESIGN_ID
    FROM DLR_CIRCUIT_DESIGN_LINE
    WHERE LOCATION LIKE '%  <some value from other code>   %')
```

Note the extra `(+)`. This is old-style join, you should now use ANSI joins instead.

Comment: Thank you, This worked as intended. database work is something just tossed at me so unfortunately I must apologize for what is most likely a very n00b question but thank you for answering so quickly.